В классе объявить не возможно, в объекте работает
class test {
    constructor() {
        (el = 2323);
        console.log(el);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => new test());


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => ({
    int: function() {
        (m = 333);
        console.log(m);
    }
}).int())

Почему в классе если необходимо занести данные в переменную, предварительно не объявляя но обрамляя в скобки. Не работает, а с объектом это работает...
В некоторых случаях, сразу заношу данные в переменную заведомо в скобках. Когда тутже необходимо к примеру повесить слушатель и еще обратиться к переменной в последующем.
Возможно запустить класс также как объект запускаю, не люблю лишних строчек...

Классы, они в первую очередь про всякие Best practices.
Никогда не сталкивался, почему вы используете скобки?

Случайно, в php так начал делать, затем попробовал в js...

К примеру необходимо повесить слушатель на элемент, а затем к элементу обраться еще раз. -1 строчка js, лишний раз не приходится объявлять

Предлагаю всё таки вернуться к вашему изначальному вопросу, приведите пример (дополнением к прошлому). что вы хотите оптимизировать, чтобы можно было говорить более объектно, а не рассматривать различные методологии наобум.

Правильный вопрос «зачем вы вообще хотите использовать переменные без объявления?»
И правильный ответ на ваш вопрос будет «так делать категорически не нужно» и, соответственно, вопрос пропадёт как неактуальный.

Подозреваю что классы по умолчанию работают в строгом режиме.
Второй вариант так же должен вызывать ошибку, если переменная заранее не объявлена.
Вот пример:
Работает


function test() {
  ({
    int: function() {
      (m = 333);
      console.log(m);
    }
  }).int()
}
test()



Не работает(use strict)


function testStrict() {
  'use strict';
  ({
    int: function() {
      (m = 333);
      console.log(m);
    }
  }).int()
}
testStrict()




Накладно получается, +1 строчка только на то что необходимо объявить...

@Роман Как бы там ни было, лучше всегда использовать строгий режим. Тем более что в TypeScript, на который все уже перешли, написать без определения переменных вообще невозможно.
